# Sequence generation based on a conditon using Informatica

Tags: sql, plsql, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I need to achieve following data transformation using Informatica,

The first picture is the sample input data

[image]

The data after transformations should look like as below,
Here for the different type I have the sequence staring from 200 in this case bfd should be considered as one group and (klm,kln) together as other group. The new id is id+the sequence number

[image]

Should I do this using UDF or by creating a procedure.. or using some sets of transformations..
I am new to informatica and am confused about what approach should I follow..
Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this using two separate sequence transformation.
first one will start from 0 and increment by 1.
second one will start from 200 and increment by 1.
Then use an `IIF` condition to generate new_id column. if you have few different type of sequence, you can do it with IIF. But if you have hundreds, probably you need to use some UDF etc.

```
seq_1 = attach NEXTVAL from sequence generator 1
seq_2 = attach NEXTVAL from sequence generator 2
new_id = TO_INTEGER ( IIF( group ='bfd', id || seq_1, 
                        IIF( group = 'klm' or group ='kln', id || seq_2) 
                       )  
                     )
```

Comment: Should I use the IIF condition through expression transformation? I am sorry if my doubt feels very basic.. but I am still in the learning phase..

Comment: yes. use expression transformation to calculate new id column.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query to do this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when group = 'bfd'
             then id * 10 + row_number() over (partition by group order by id)
             when group in ('klm', 'kln')
             then id * 100 + row_number() over (partition by case when group in ('klm', 'kln') then 1 else 2 end order by id)
        end) as new_id
from t;
```

Comment: Yes! I have an SQL Oracle query for the same scenario.. but I am unaware of the ways I could use it or integrate it within informatica Powercenter

Comment: Yes yes..it is .. I just wanted to know if I can use SQL transformation into it! Thanks for the help! :)